# Timer Changing Every Game

Tags: ios, swift, timer

For some reason when I play a game the first time, everything works fine and my timer does something when it ends every 2 seconds. When I play again the second time, it does something every one second.

```
var masterTimer: NSTimer? = nil
```

in the viewDidLoad:

```
self.masterTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "First", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

TimeLeft1 equals 2 and Difficulty equals 3

```
var TimeLeft1 = defaults.integerForKey("TimeLeft1")
var ScoreType = defaults.integerForKey("ScoreType")
    var Difficulty = defaults.integerForKey("Difficulty")

TimeLeft1 -= 1 //take a second away
    defaults.setInteger(TimeLeft1, forKey: "TimeLeft1")
    if (TimeLeft1 > 0)
    {

    }
    else
    {

        if Difficulty == 1 {
            TimeLeft1 += 5
            defaults.setInteger(TimeLeft1, forKey: "TimeLeft1")
        }
        else if Difficulty == 2 {
            TimeLeft1 += 3
            defaults.setInteger(TimeLeft1, forKey: "TimeLeft1")
        }
        else if Difficulty == 3 {
            TimeLeft1 += 2
            defaults.setInteger(TimeLeft1, forKey: "TimeLeft1")
        }
```

Comment: You are scheduling your timer to execute every one second.  Do you ever call `timer.invalidate()` ?

Comment: I am scheduling my timer to change every second, but I only want to do something after it ends which is after 2 seconds. And yes I do masterTimer.invalidate() at the end of the game.

Comment: Using `NSUserDefaults` for transitory state data is not very efficient and may be causing your problems.  Why not use a simple property?

Comment: I am letting people choose between a variety of difficulties and saving their choice with NSUserDefaults.

Comment: That is fine, but `timeLeft1` seems to be a simple integer variable.  Continually reading/writing it to NSUserDefaults is inefficient

Comment: TimeLeft1 could be 2,3, or 5.

Comment: Don't confuse the initial value (which is related to the difficulty) with the current value (which is related to how much time has elapsed).

Comment: I am not, the initial time could also be 2,3, or 5 but I am using the example of 2 because I am not having many problems with the other two.

Comment: My suspicion is that your `TimeLeft1` is -1, not 0 so when you add 2 you get 1.  You should set a breakpoint and see what is happening.  Why do you use the `+=` syntax when you could use simple assignment `=`?  Also, by convention class names start with an uppercase letter, variables start with a lower case letter (so `timeLeft1` not `TimeLeft1`)